# numpy: check for 1 every 6 element every row

Tags: python, numpy

I need to have something like this:

```
arr = array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Where each row contains 36 elements, every 6 element in a row represents a hidden row, and that hidden row needs exactly one `1`, and `0` everywhere else. In other words, every entry mod 6 needs exactly one `1`. This is my requirement for `arr`.

---

I have a table that's going to be used to compute a "fitness" value for each row. That is, I have a

```
table = np.array([10, 5, 4, 6, 5, 1, 6, 4, 9, 7, 3, 2, 1, 8, 3,
                          6, 4, 6, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 8, 7, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3, 2])
table = table.T
```

and I'm going to multiply each row of `arr` with `table`. The result of that multiplication, a `1x1` matrix, will be stored as the "fitness" value of that corresponding row. **UNLESS** the row does not fit the requirement described above, which should return 0.

an example of what should be returned is

```
result = array([5,12,13,14,20,34])
```

I need a way to do this but I'm too new to numpy to know how to.

Comment: What do you mean by "check this" ?
do you need to test if given array is of that form or do you need to create such an array? Please provide the steps that you tried and the results

Comment: use `<your_array>.reshape(-1, 6, 6)` then you can sum along `axis` 1, compare the result to `1` and use `np.all` on the resulting boolean array.

Comment: added clarification @srj

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want. For the first half, I think ` np.all(arr[:,6] == 1) and np.all(arr[:, :6] == 0) and np.all(arr[:, 7:])` should work. I am almost sure that there is a better way for this :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm Assuming you want what you've asked for in the first half).

I believe better or more elegant solutions exist, but this is what I think can do the job.

```
np.all(arr[:,6] == 1) and np.all(arr[:, :6] == 0) and np.all(arr[:, 7:])
```

Alternatively, you can construct the array (with 0's and 1's) and then just compare with it, say using [not_equal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.not_equal.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not 100% sure of your question, but I'll try to answer with the best of my knowledge.

Since you're saying your matrix has "hidden rows", to check whether it is well formed, the easiest way seems to be to just reshape it:

```
# First check, returns true if all elements are either 0 or 1
np.in1d(arr, [0,1]).all()
# Second check, provided the above was True, returns True if
# each "hidden row" has exactly one 1 and other 0.
(arr.reshape(6,6,6).sum(axis=2) == 1).all()
```

Both checks return "True" for your `arr`.

Now, my understanding is that for each "large" row of 36 elements, you want a scalar product with your "table" vector, unless that "large" row has an ill-formed "hidden small" row. In this case, I'd do something like:

```
# The following computes the result, not checking for integrity
results = arr.dot(table)
# Now remove the results that are not well formed.
# First, compute "large" rows where at least one "small" subrow
# fails the condition.
mask = (arr.reshape(6,6,6).sum(axis=2) != 1).any(axis=1)
# And set the corresponding answer to 0
results[mask] = 0
```

However, running this code against your data returns as answer

> array([38, 31, 24, 24, 32, 20])

which is not what you mention; did I misunderstand your requirement, or was the example based on different data?